# Use String to call a Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

In my case:
I have **listTemplates** the same:

```
List<TemplateModel> listTemplate = [
TemplateModel(
    id: 1,
    name: 'Temp_1',
    previewBack: AppImages.TEMP_1,
    previewFront: AppImages.TEMP_1,),
TemplateModel(
    id: 2,
    name: 'Temp_2',
    previewBack: AppImages.TEMP_2,
    previewFront: AppImages.TEMP_2),
TemplateModel(
    id: 3,
    name: 'Temp_3',
    previewBack: AppImages.TEMP_3,
    previewFront: AppImages.TEMP_3),
TemplateModel(
    id: 4,
    name: 'Temp_4',
    previewBack: AppImages.TEMP_4,
    previewFront: AppImages.TEMP_4),
  ];
```

And I also have **Temp_1()**, **Temp_2()**, **Temp_3()**, **Temp_4()** Widgets.

I want to show each by name of template
ex:

```
Container(
    child: `Temp_1`(), // It's my explain to try to show my problem, of course, it's not work.
);
```

I don't want to use **if-else** or **switch-case** for this case becuase I have the too large list templates.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's not support now. Do you use right solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Another option you can use - Map<int, Widget>.

```
final temperatureUI = {
    1: Temp_1(),
    ...
}
```

and then

```
Container(
    child: temperatureUI[templateModel.id],
);
```